# Difference between the suffixes -ation and -ierung

Tags: difference

Is there a difference between the German suffixes -ation and -ierung?

Examples are

- Identifikation vs. Identifizierung
- Publikation vs Publizierung

Comment: I would recommend to change this to *-tion* and *-ierung*, see *Abstraktion* and *Abstrahierung*.

Comment: Also, I think that the *-ierung* form more or less describes the action, while the *-tion* form describes the state itself. Nevertheless I can't really explain it nor have any reference besides my feeling.

Comment: @ RoyPJ: Right, I did no think of that case. I edited the question.

Comment: Also consider that `-(at)ion` always denotes a Latin word, or a germanized Latin word, likewise `-ierung` is also of Latin origin ;-) — the pure ending `-ung` actually seems to be more characteristic of real German words, example: Reformation (=germanized Latin) ⇌ Umgestaltung, Wiederumwandlung (=actually German). But I would also say, that `-ierung` is the doing, wheras `-ation` is rather the thing itself: Publizierung (the doing, process), Publikation (the thing itself, it is done) = das Veröffentlichen, die Veröffentlichung (=actually German, veröffentlicht is put openly litteraly)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As RoyPJ mentions and the German Duden denotes the following differences:

- mostly, in common usage, they can be used both ways.
- sometimes, there is the subtle difference between indication of action and indication of state.

  - the suffix "ation" denotes the result of an action,
  - the suffix "ierung" the action itself.
    But, as a native speaker of German, this is subtle in many situations.

My source (in German) is https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/_ation__ierung

Comment: Thanks PiedPiper and others for correction of my English - all my I* products I use from time to time do correct my English writings to German, and I always try to correct back... Typing on a IPhone with default language German is hard under these circumstances.

Answer (score 9):

`-ation` tends to denote a process as a whole or a notion, possibly even an object (cf. *Publikation* in the sense of published work as a printed artifact, *Spezifikation* as a technical document ), while `-ierung` focuses on the process over time. Examples would be:

- Abstraktion - Abstrahierung
- Indikation - Indizierung
- Publikation - Publizierung
- Spezifikation - Spezifizierung

I cannot provide a reference other than the intuition of a native speaker. I *can*, however, give evidence that the difference is not clear-cut. In particular there are word pairs where the individual items carry wildly differing meanings and which cannot be substituted for each other:

- Differentiation - Differenzierung ( math. operation vs attention to differences in detail )
- Kontraktion - Kontrahierung ( redution in volume vs. establishing a contract )
- Reservation - Reservierung ( segregated territory vs. booking in advance )