# Erkunden and Erfahren

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar-identification

> Durch das Erkunden und Erfahren der Umwelt eignet sich ein Kind die notwendigen Fähigkeiten an, Sachverhalte selbstständig zu erfassen und zu verstehen.

What does *Erkunden and Erfahren* mean in the above? I checked three dictionaries: Pons, Collins and Leo and none have the meaning. It seems however that "Erkundung" and "Erfahrung" are indeed nouns.

This post seems related but doesn't give me enough details: [Nouns formed from verb stem with -en and -ung endings](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/43712/nouns-formed-from-verb-stem-with-en-and-ung-endings)

Answer (score 8):

In German you can turn any verb into a noun by capitalizing its infinitive form; such a noun is always neuter. So *das Erkunden* and *das Erfahren* are nouns like *das Gehen*, *das Fahren*, *das Tippen* or any other verb where that makes sense.

erkunden = to explore; erfahren = to experience

So I would translate that sentence fragment as follows:

> By exploring and experiencing the environment, a child …

Answer (score 2):

You are right, these are nouns, which is easy to tell since all nouns are always capitalized in German. And the fact, that you referred to a question concerning nouns formed from verbs, shows, that you already know, that the origin of these nouns are verbs.

The process of creation of nouns from words that by themselves are not nouns is called "nominalization" in English or "Substantivierung" in German. And this mechanism is very productive in German and also in English. The words "process", "creation" and "nominalization" are English examples and "Substantivierung" is a German example for products of this mechanism.

There are many different ways to create nouns from non-nouns, and they all are called "nominalization" in a wider sense, but nominalization in it's most narrow meaning just means the usage of the infinite form of a verb as a noun. This is possible in German with (almost?) all verbs. (At the moment I'm not aware of any exceptions, but that doesn't mean that there aren't some.) And it is also possible in English with some verbs.

- English examples:

  > Verb *to change*: I will **change.**
  > Noun *the change*: I need a **change.**
  >
  > Verb *to walk*: Let's **walk.**
  > Noun *the walk*: Let's go for a **walk.**
  >
  > Verb *to murder*: Erika wanted to **murder** him.
  > Noun *the murder*: It was a cruel **murder.**
- German examples:

  > Verb *gehen*: Ich werde **gehen.**
  > Substantiv: Das **Gehen** bereitet mir Mühe.
  >
  > Verb *schreiben*: Ich werde einen Brief **schreiben.**
  > Substantiv *Schreiben*: Durch das viele **Schreiben** hat sich bei mir eine Sehne entzündet.
  >
  > Verb *rauchen*: Ich habe aufgehört zu **rauchen.**
  > Substantiv *Rauchen*: Das **Rauchen** ist hier verboten.

The two nouns from your sentence are made by the same mechanism:

> Verb *erkunden*: Wir möchten die Umgebung **erkunden.**
> Substantiv *Erkunden*: Durch das **Erkunden** der Umgebung gewinnt man neue Erkenntnisse.
>
> Verb *erfahren*: Ich habe nichts neues **erfahren.**
> Substantiv *Erfahren*: Das **Erfahren** von Schmerzen ist ein sehr negatives Erlebnis.

---

Translations:

> - Ich werde gehen.
>   I will go. I will leave. I will walk.
> - Das Gehen bereitet mir Mühe.
>   Walking gives me trouble. I have trouble walking.
> - Ich werde einen Brief schreiben.
>   I will write a letter.
> - Durch das viele Schreiben hat sich bei mir eine Sehne entzündet.
>   Due to all the writing, a tendon has become inflamed in me.
> - Ich habe aufgehört zu rauchen.
>   I stopped smoking.
> - Das Rauchen ist hier verboten.
>   Smoking is prohibited here.
> - Wir möchten die Umgebung erkunden.
>   We would like to explore the surrounding area.
> - Durch das Erkunden der Umgebung gewinnt man neue Erkenntnisse.
>   By the exploration of the environment, you gain new knowledge.
>   By exploring the environment, you gain new knowledge.
> - Ich habe nichts neues erfahren.
>   I have not heard/learned anything new.
> - Das Erfahren von Schmerzen ist ein sehr negatives Erlebnis.
>   The experience of pain is a very negative experience.
>   Experiencing pain is a very negative experience.

> - Durch das Erkunden und Erfahren der Umwelt eignet sich ein Kind die notwendigen Fähigkeiten an, Sachverhalte selbstständig zu erfassen und zu verstehen.
>   Through the exploration and the experiencing of the environment, a child acquires the necessary skills to grasp and understand facts independently.
>   By exploring and experiencing the environment, a child acquires the necessary skills to grasp and understand facts independently.